# python group and manipulate similar values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have integrated a dataset (csv) into a pandas dataframe. One of the columns contains several 'levels' or unique values which have similar context. I therefore want to combine those to one common value. 
Two issues I am facing with this particular column are:

1. The column is of type object, so I tried to convert to string (str).
   I attempted to convert the column to a string but then python displays an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)".
2. Several of these values contain German characters. I attempted to replace the German characters to normal (such as ä to ae etc). No values were manipulated.

`df.replace(u'\xe4', 'ae')`

Two ways of reading in data didn't help:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=True, encoding='utf-8',header=0)
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=True, encoding='utf-8',header=0, dtype={'a': str})
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```

dataset sample (2 columns):

```
     a       |     b   |     c * (new column)  
    ===============================
    häfen1         1       häfen1 
    häfen2         1       häfen2
    haefen-1       0       häfen1
    haefen1        1       häfen1
    häfen2         0       häfen2
    häfen3         0       häfen3
    häfen3         0       häfen3
    haefen 1       1       häfen1
```

Comment: Is possible share `csv` with sample? Or maybe `csv` with real data, if not confidental?

Comment: You said: "I therefore want to combine those to one common value." What do you mean by one common value?

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion. Unfortunately i cannot publish the data, so I prepared this small sample and for convenience. The entries for instance ( häfen1, haefen-1,haefen1, haefen 1) mean the same thing contextually, the only difference is that the user manually entered the data. I want to manipulate 'column  a' to a new column for all of those entries and instead input häfen1 for example.

Comment: @jezrael what can i do to give you a better example.

Comment: @OAK - I dont solve your question, because you write that read csv doesnt work. So if I cannot read csv, I think it is problem solve rename problem.

Comment: Or you can read csv and problem is only with rename? I am just a little bit confused...

Comment: @jezrael the problem is not reading in the csv. The problem is that I cannot figure out the correct way of merging similar values in 'column a' (values are  similar in terms of context not equal). So (häfen1, haefen-1,haefen1, haefen 1) has the same meaning and therefore should have the value of häfen1 in 'column c'. I think the problem is that column a is of type object and not string and also the German characters which are not encoded properly when I try to turn 'column a' to string.

Comment: @OAK, can you try this? df.loc[df['a'].str.contains(u'\bhafen.*'), 'c'] = 'hafen'

Comment: @Abbas , thanks that worked!.